# Custom NSTextView insertText:replacementRange breaks Spell Checking

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, spell-checking, nstextview

I have a custom NSTextView subclass, with a custom NSTextStorage component as well.  The NSTextStorage modifies the text entered by the user based on context.

Because it's possible that the final text will be shorter than the text originally entered by the user, I had to override `insertText:replacementRange` in my NSTextView.  A minimum example is:

```
- (void) insertText:(id)string replacementRange:(NSRange)replacementRange {
    if ([self hasMarkedText]) {
        [[self textStorage] replaceCharactersInRange:[self markedRange] withString:string];
    } else {
        [[self textStorage] replaceCharactersInRange:[self selectedRange] withString:string];
    }

    [self didChangeText];
}
```

This works fine in extensive testing over several months.... Except that automatic spell checking and correction is disabled.  The "squigglies" don't appear under misspelled words, unless I stop typing, move the mouse, and switch focus to and from my app.  After several seconds, the entire textview is spellcheck'ed.  Because it happens after the fact, automatic correction is disabled of course.

If I disable my custom `insertText:replacementRange:` method, everything else works fine, and automatic spelling functionality returns.  I just have to be careful not to trigger a change that results in shortening the text, as it triggers attribute out of range errors (the original reason for my custom method in the first place.)

Apparently Apple's implementation of `insertText:replacementRange:` does much more than mine.  I have tried multiple variations on `[self checkTextInRange...]`, `[self checkTextInSelection:]`, etc.  None of them restore proper functionality.

Searching Apple's documentation doesn't help point me towards what I am leaving out from my method that is causing spell checking to break.  Any pointers or ideas would be much appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Here are some examples of the sorts of behavior my NSTextStorage provides. (`|` represents the insertion caret)

Starting with:

```
* item
* |
```

If I hit the return key, I end up with the following (deleting `*<space>`):

```
* item
|
```

Another example, if "Change Tracking" is enabled:

```
this is thee| time
```

If I hit delete:

```
this is the|{--e--} time
```

As you can see, a single keystroke may result in the addition or deletion of multiple characters from the text.

**EDIT 2**: FYI -- the issue I have with attributes being out of range occur when the shortening happens while pressing return at the end of the document -- NSTextview attempts to set a new paragraph style only to find that the document is shorter than expected.  I can find no way to change the range NSTextview targets.

Comment: How do you modify the text storage? Do you call any `beginEditing`, `endEditing`, `edited:range:changeInLength:` or something?

Comment: Yes -- all three.  And everything in NSTextStorage works perfectly (at least during my months and months of use).  The only problem I have been able to find is the spelling issue, which is fixed as above -- disable custom `insertText:replacementRange:` (but still using my custom NSTextStorage) and spelling returns.

Comment: Apparently you can't fix the attribute out of range errors by replacing `insertText:replacementRange:`. Where do the errors come from?

Comment: One possible behavior when typing is that hitting return key can actually delete characters before the insertion point, causing the string to be shorter than it was when the user hit enter.  At some point during Apple's `insertText...` method, it requests the attributes from NSTextStorage, expecting that the string is longer than it is.  I tried sending back fake attributes, but that compounded the problem.  By overriding the method, I left out the broken part, but apparently left out something I want as well.... ;)

Comment: In which methods of `NSTextStorage` and `NSTextStorageDelegate` do you modify the text?

Comment: `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`.  I could be missing something, but I *really* think the problem is in NSTextView, not NSTextStorage.  As I mentioned, all is fine if I disable my custom `insertText:replacementRange` method and keep using my custom NSTextStorage.

Comment: The problem is you messing with the text storage when `NSTextView` is using it. Did you try doing the modifications in `textStorage:willProcessEditing:range:changeInLength:`?

Comment: From what I can tell, that notification is sent to late for me to do what is needed -- I need access to the original text before changes and the proposed new text in order to calculate the proper result.  I'll add an example to the question for further clarification of what might happen.

Comment: Also -- it seems as if that notification is not sent during programmatic changes to the text.  I need a single point of control to ensure consistency.  My older version of the software did not use NSTextStorage in quite this way -- spelling worked fine, but I did not have consistent control over the behavior

Comment: I tried subclassing `NSTextStorage`, overriding `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` and deleting text when I paste something. I don't get any out of range errors.

Comment: I would respectively suggest that we stick to the question at hand -- the NSTextView and NSTextStorage arrangement is complex, and again, working fine otherwise.  I'm not trying to troubleshoot that.  For the moment, assume that I *need* to override `insertText...` and want to get spelling working.  I'll keep digging into whether I can avoid that requirement, but that requires a great deal more background information that is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(EDITED 2018-05-30)

Updated response (2018-05-22):

This issue reared its ugly head again, and I really needed to figure it out.

1. My custom NSTextStorage is fundamentally the same as described, and still works.
2. I use a custom `insertText:replacementRange:` on my NSTextView, but it calls `[super insertText:replacementRange:]` to take advantage of Apple's behind-the-scenes work that makes spelling, etc. work better.  My custom method only needs to set a boolean.
3. When shortening the text, I still get requests from Apple's `insertText:replacementRange:` for attributes in a non-existent part of the text.  Previously, I would get stuck here, because everything I tried either caused a crash, or caused Apple's code to repeatedly request the non-existing attributes indefinitely.
4. Finally, I tried returning fake attributes with a NULL rangepointer, and this seems to make Apple's code happy:

   ```
   - (NSDictionary *) attributesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)location effectiveRange:(nullable NSRangePointer)range {
       if (location > _backingAttributes.length) {
           // This happens if we shrink the text before the textview is aware of it.
           // For example, if we expand "longtext" -> "short" in our smart string, then
           // The textview may set and request attributes past the end of our
           // _backing string.
           // Initially this was due to error in my code, but now I had to add
           // This error checking back
           NSLog(@"get attributes at (%lu) in (%lu)", (unsigned long)location, (unsigned long)_backingAttributes.length);
           NSLog(@"error");

           // Apparently returning fake attributes satisfies [NSTextView insertText:replacementRange:]
           range = NULL;
           return  @{
                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [BIColor redColor],
                     NSFontAttributeName : [BIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]
                     };

       } else {
           return [_backingAttributes attributesAtIndex:location effectiveRange:range];
       }
   }
   ```
5. With further testing, this turned out to not be quite enough.  I ended up adding the following to the setter to store the invalid attributes and range that macOS was trying to set:

   ```
   - (void) setAttributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)attrs range:(NSRange)range {
       if (NSMaxRange(range) > _backingAttributes.length) {
           _invalidAttrs = attrs;
           _invalidRange = range;
       } else {
           [self beginEditing];
           [_backingAttributes setAttributes:attrs range:range];
           [self edited:NSTextStorageEditedAttributes range:range changeInLength:0];
           [self endEditing];
       }
   }
   ```
6. I updated `attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange: to return the following when called with an invalid range, rather than returning the fake attributes above:

   ```
   // Apparently returning fake attributes satisfies [NSTextView insertText]
   *range = _invalidRange;
   return _invalidAttrs;
   ```

This seems to work under various conditions that would previously trigger an exception or an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution.

In my custom `insertText:replacementRange:` method, prior to `didChangeText`:

```
NSinteger wordCount;
NSOrthography * orthography;

static NSInteger theWordCount;
NSOrthography  * orthography;

NSRange spellingRange = <range to check>

NSArray * results = [[NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker] checkString:[[self textStorage] string]
                                                               range:spellingRange
                                                               types:[self enabledTextCheckingTypes]
                                                             options:NULL
                                              inSpellDocumentWithTag:0
                                                         orthography:&orthography
                                                           wordCount:&theWordCount];
if (results.count) {
    [self handleTextCheckingResults:results forRange:spellingRange types:[self enabledTextCheckingTypes] options:@{} orthography:orthography wordCount:theWordCount];
}
```

However, this is incomplete:

- Spell check and Grammar check works fine
- Automatic spelling correction and text replacement do not work (even when enabled)

Comment: I realized I forgot to update this.  I was able to get things working (at least 99% of the time.)  Enabling Grammar checking required extending the range to check to include an entire sentence.  I also had to be a more proscriptive and explicitly check and set the checkingtypes at various points, rather than rely on `[self enabledTextCheckingTypes].  In short, it required a lot of hoop  jumping and is still not perfect.

Comment: I was finally able to solve the original issue that required the workaround.  So I no longer need to customize `insertText:replacementRange:`.  Which means vastly improved spell-checking performance.  So, I strongly recommend avoiding that route if you can help it.  ;)